# The method is triggered twice from the control event handler?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have some checkboxes in a group and the following is the event handler and the related method.

```
public async void CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"Calling CheckedChanged {s.Name}: {s.CheckState}");
    await Filter();
}

public async Task Filter()
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"Calling Filter");
    // ....
}
```

However, the following debug output shows the method `Filter` was called twice for each state change of the checkboxes.

```
Calling CheckedChanged CheckBox1: Checked
Calling Filter 
Calling Filter
Calling CheckedChanged CheckBox1: Unchecked
Calling Filter
Calling Filter
```

The method `Filter` has some very expensive database calls and the SQL Profiler shows these calls are invoked twice too.

---

It turns out there method `Filter` was called in a `Task.Run(...)` and the debugger couldn't get the caller. The accepted answer helped to find it out.

Comment: Is `Filter` called anywhere else?  Based on the code you've shown there's no obvious reason for the results you are seeing.

Comment: This code does not behave like that, even if I add what I presume the missing line to be: `var s = sender as CheckBox;`. I only get `Calling Filter` once each time. Please provide a [mcve]; I suspect you'll find the problem as you try to whittle it down.

Comment: The snippet is inadequate to explain this.  Just beware of the *other* thing that can easily go wrong with this code.  If you don't do anything to prevent the user from using the control again while Filter() is grinding away then you can easily get to call Filter again, before the previous invocation is completed.  That does not often come to a good end.  You must use the control's Enabled property to prevent this kind of DoEvents-style re-entrancy problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure that Filter method is called only from CheckedChanged?
Try something like this

```
    public async void CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"Calling CheckedChanged {s.Name}: {s.CheckState}");
    await Filter(nameof("CheckedChanged"));
}

public async Task Filter(string caller = "undefined")
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"Calling Filter from {caller}");
    // ....
}
```

Comment: I wouldn't mind the upvotes, and this being marked as the accepted answer if this actually compiled. You need to remove the quotes inside `nameof`; but even then, you'd be better just putting a breakpoint on it, and looking at the stack.

Comment: You can let the compiler add in the caller information by marking the parameter with the appropriate attribute: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/caller-information